# Accessing AWS Website to change one .html file

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, webserver, web-deployment

For some time ago (years) I deployed a website made with Django in AWS, now I'm trying to make some changes in just one .html file but I don't remember how to connect to my instance anymore, I tried to look at the documentation from AWS but there is too many changes and also they added a lot of new components, that I don't know where to start and I also don't remember correctly how it worked.

[image]

Unfortunately all the private keys, password and this kind of stuff are in a old computer that I don't even have anymore. The only thing that I have is the username, password from my AWS console and a Mac.

I would appreciate if you can point me out where to start!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. Personally, I would find the EC2 instance your site is hosted on and create an image of it. This can be done by selecting your instance in the EC2 console. This will create an Amazon Machine Imagine (AMI). You can then launch a new EC2 instance from this AMI and specify a new PEM key. Once the instance is launched, you can connect to the instance and edit the .html file.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an AMI (Amazon Machine Image) of any running EC2 servers (where your application likely lives).

After creating an AMI, you can spin up a *new* EC2 instance using that AMI. The new one will be a clone of the old one, but you can specify/download a new keypair.

From there you can log in via ssh, and I'd recommend putting things in *source control* afterwards.

A lot of the rest depends on your DNS settings... if you're using an Elastic IP you can just assign it to the new machine. If you're using an Elastic Load Balancer you can simply move the old one off, and the new one on.